# How to properly use aria selectors for definition lists in puppeteer

Tags: html, accessibility, puppeteer, ui-automation, wai-aria

I'm writing some UI functional tests using `puppeteer`. After discovering the ["Puppetaria" article](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/puppetaria/), I decided that whenever it's possible, I want to use aria selectors. This has been working OK in many cases, but I'm struggling to figure out how to properly do this using a [`<dl/>` definition list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl). I'm using a `<dl/>` to show details about an object in the hopes that it's an accessible way to present things. For example:

```
<dl>
  <dt>ID</dt>
  <dd>6234</dd>

  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>Yo Mama</dd>
</dl>
```

It seems like *semantically*, the `<dt/>` elements *label* the `<dd/>`'s. However, when I use the puppeteer selector `aria/ID` I get back *nothing* and time out waiting on the selector.

I do see that if I *explicitly* describe that an element labels the other:

```
<dl>
  <dt id="id-label">ID</dt>
  <dd aria-labelledby="id-label">6234</dd>
</dl>
```

...then the `aria/ID` selector works.

Am I doing accessibility wrong making the assumption that `dt` and `dd` semantically align without explicit annotations? Am I using Puppeteer  incorrectly? Or is this a bug with Chrome's accessibility tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition lists kind of suck when it comes to accessibility.  In your example, you have two terms and two definitions. When you navigate through the list with a screen reader, some screen readers will say the list has 2 items and some will say it has 4 items and some will say there isn't a list.

Technically, a `<dl>` does not have a `list` role [by default](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-dl) so screen readers that say there isn't a list are correct.

I have not used puppeteer but from what I understand, the [aria selector](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/puppetaria/#syntactic-vs-semantic-selectors) is looking for the [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name).  The [accessible name calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2) follows a set of rules (essentially a big if-then-else statement).  `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements do not have an accessible name unless you use `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`.  They're not like `<button>` elements where a button can get its accessible name from the "contents" of the button (the text between the `<button>` and `</button>`), step 2.F in the calculation.  So the text between a `<dt>` and `</dt>` is **not** the accessible name and thus not returned in a puppeteer aria selector.