# Can we use different `<dl>` element for each `<dt>`, `<dd>` pair?

Tags: html, accessibility

Can we use a different `<dl>` for each `<dt>`, `<dd>` pairs? Will there be any problems with accessibility if we do it? Use-case being to simplify some Component API. For example:

```html
<!-- Can we do this -->
<div class="container">
  <dl>
    <dt>First Name</dt>
    <dd>Jeff</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>Last Name</dt>
    <dd>Bezos</dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<!-- instead of this? -->
<div class="container">
  <dl>
    <dt>First Name</dt>
    <dd>Jeff</dd>

    <dt>Last Name</dt>
    <dd>Bezos</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on whether those are two different lists semantically. This looks like a single list so you should not split it into two dls

Comment: According to the content of the `<dt>` I'd say it's OK.

Comment: @zer00ne A list of one item?

Comment: @JuanMendes Alright. Makes sense.

Comment: @JuanMendes If OPs example is minimal representation, yes. If it is the literal representation, then not worth considering in the first place.

Comment: @zer00ne Actually, it is quite similar to my actual problem. I have a bunch of meta properties for a model of a car.

Comment: @VighneshRaut A single car then a single `<dl>` is probably adequate. Semantics is subjective and never 100%.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it doesn't matter because definition lists suck in general for accessibility purposes.  See my (editorial) comment in this answer, [How to properly use aria selectors for definition lists in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71745939/how-to-properly-use-aria-selectors-for-definition-lists-in-puppeteer/71754428#71754428)

A definition list does not have a ["list" role](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-dl) by default so different screen readers interpret them differently.  Because of this, whether you have separate `<dl>`s or not won't have a huge impact.

"Real" lists, `<ul>` and `<ol>`, **do** make a difference.  If you have a group of things that are related and are contained in one list, then it should only be one `<ul>` rather than a series of `<ul>`s.  A screen reader conveys metadata information about lists such as the number of elements in the list.  You get that information "for free" with your eyes if you're sighted.  You can generally tell how many items are in a list (if it's not too long) whereas a screen reader user doesn't have that "seeing" option so the screen reader can tell them it's a list with 5 items, but only if it's a single `<ul>` with 5 `<li>` elements.